# What is the best way to check if table exists in DynamoDB?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

What is the best way to check if table exists in DynamoDb?

I would appreciate it if the code would be in PHP.

Either active or not.

*** Added later as an example to various cases for error code 400

It's very easy to check if the table exist, it can have one of the following 
TableStatus => CREATING, ACTIVE, DELETING or UPDATING

but in case i get error 400 it can mean more than one thing.

1) sent null string as a table name by mistake.

[x-aws-body] => {"TableName":""}
        )

```
[body] => CFSimpleXML Object
    (
        [__type] => com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException
        [message] => The paramater 'tableName' must be at least 3 characters long and at most 255 characters long
    )

[status] => 400
```

2) syntax error in the command sent to DynamoDB, for example writting tabel_name instead of table_name.

[x-aws-body] => {"TabelName":"test7"}
        )

```
[body] => CFSimpleXML Object
    (
        [__type] => com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException
        [message] => The paramater 'tableName' is required but was not present in the request
    )

[status] => 400
```

3) I would guess but didn't check, if I exceed at that same time the provisioned capacity on the table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have a look at "**describe_table**" of the official PHP SDK. **400** means "**does not exist**" There is a pretty extensive example in the official documentation. Look at how it is used in the "delete" example, right at the bottom.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPTableOperationsExample.html

Here is the (stripped) example from the doc

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/sdk/sdk.class.php';

$dynamodb = new AmazonDynamoDB();
$table_name = 'ExampleTable';
$response = $dynamodb->describe_table(array('TableName' => $table_name));

if((integer) $response->status !== 400)
{
    $error_type = $response->body->__type;
    $error_code = explode('#', $error_type)[1];
    if($error_code == 'ResourceNotFoundException')
    {
        echo "Table ".$table_name." exists.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I can't yet find the error code list for dynamodb, but what I know is that error code 400 is used when you exceed your provisioned limit so it will be a problem to rely on it.

Comment: Quote from amazon docs -> "If your application performs more reads/second or writes/second than your table’s provisioned throughput capacity allows, requests above your provisioned capacity will be throttled and you will receive 400 error codes."

Comment: I need to do a manual check if Error code 404 works fine with describe table

Comment: @WizCat: it's from the official doc ! Check the link above.

Comment: I apologize in case i am missing something, but I cannot see any code other than 400 in the above link! Where can I find a reference for code 404 regarding dynamodb?

Comment: In case the table does not exist, 400 is returned because this is considered as a bad request. You can not describe a non existing table.

Comment: my fear is that there are other conditions that can get me error code 400 while i do have the table. since error code 400 is widely used for "bad requests" which can mean allot of things.

Comment: There won't, it is documented here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_DescribeTables.html. Anyway, you can use ``$dynamodb->list_tables()`` and check if your table in the array.

Comment: I like the list table option. maybe i will use that, since i can show you at least two other cases with describe_table where i get status 400 and it have nothing to do with the table existence. that's why i like the list table solution much better. I will check this out.

Comment: @WizCat http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ErrorHandling.html#APIError

Comment: It's better to use DescribeTable than ListTables. If you have hundreds of tables in your account, you are sending a lot of extra data over the wire for no reason. See my answer with the `doesTableExist` code sample for a way to make it work with DescribeTable.

Comment: thanks @JeremyLindblom, as I explained above code 400 can mean lot of thing, not necessarily table doesn't exist, more like table not available. but i take your comment as to be careful when I have a long list of tables. need to figure that out. other option that I was considering is checking the error message it self, and pick the one that indicates that the table doesn't exist.

Comment: In DynamoDb, error code 400 almost mean nothing alone. You **need** to **check the body** for the specific reason leading to 400. In your case, it is "**ResourceNotFoundException**".

Comment: @WizCat I added a example code on this thread using DescribeTable that handles the response code and body in the way that you need. Please see my answer (currently below this one) as I think it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Some of these answers are using the older SDK's and so I thought I'd update this useful question with what I coded up and works well.  The newer exceptions really do make this task easier. This function gives you a nice boolean to use in scripts.

```
use Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException; // <-- make sure this line is at the top

    public function TableExists($tableName) {

    $ddb = DynamoDbClient::factory(array('region' => 'us-east-1')); // EC2 role security

    try {
        $result = $ddb->describeTable(array(
            "TableName" => $tableName
        ));
    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
        // if this exception is thrown, the table doesn't exist
        return false;
    }

    // no exception thrown? table exists!
    return true;
}
```

Hopefully this *complete* working code helps some of you.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer that solves this with `describeTable` is a good one, but fooling around with the status code response makes the code less readable and more confusing.

I chose to check for a tables existence using `listTables`. Here are the **[docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_listTables)**

```
$tableName = 'my_table';

$client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array('region' => 'us-west-2'));

$response = $client->listTables();

if (!in_array($tableName, $response['TableNames'])) {
    // handle non-existence.
    // throw an error if you want or whatever
}

// handle existence
echo "Table " . $tableName . " exists";
```

Answer (score 3):

With DynamoDB you need to parse the contents of the error message in order to know what type of error you received since the status code is almost always 400. Here is a sample function that could work to determine if a table exists. It also allows you to specify a status as well if you want to check if it exists *and* if it is in a certain state.

```
<?php

function doesTableExist(AmazonDynamoDB $ddb, $tableName, $desiredStatus = null)
{
    $response = $ddb->describe_table(array('TableName' => $tableName));

    if ($response->isOK()) {
        if ($desiredStatus) {
            $status = $response->body->Table->TableStatus->to_string();
            return ($status === $desiredStatus);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } elseif ($response->status === 400) {
        $error = explode('#', $response->body->__type->to_string());
        $error = end($error);
        if ($error === 'ResourceNotFoundException') {
            return false;
        }
    }

    throw new DynamoDB_Exception('Error performing the DescribeTable operation.');
}
```

**Update**: In the AWS SDK for PHP 2, [specific exceptions are thrown](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/tree/master/src/Aws/DynamoDb/Exception) by the DynamoDB client, making this way easier to handle. Also, there are "Waiter" objects, [including one for this use case](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/DynamoDb/Waiter/TableExists.php) ([see usage in the unit test](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/tests/Aws/Tests/DynamoDb/Waiter/TableExistsTest.php#L31)) that is designed to sleep until the table exists.

Answer (score 2):

With dynamodb cli you can do it very simple as follows:

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name "my-table"
```

If the table exists it returns

```
0 -- Command was successful. There were no errors thrown by either the CLI or by the service the request was made to.
```

If the table does not exist it returns

```
255 -- Command failed. There were errors thrown by either the CLI or by the service the request was made to.
```

See also:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/describe-table.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/return-codes.html

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are correct if you just want to know whether the table exist or not. I want to make another helpful point here in case.

One should be very careful in multi-threaded or production level code.

Assuming that one thread deleted the table, **then you will still get the answer that the table exists** in answer to your query from second thread, until the table is fully deleted. In such case, once the table is deleted, the table handle in second thread is zombie, like the dangling pointer error in C++.