# DescribeTable Error Type, Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

*I am referencing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12282698/3469725) to another, very similar question (the only difference being the use of PHP).*

I have seen an example of getting detailed error information from an exception throw by AWS DynamoDB's `DescribeTable` method in PHP (see above linked answer); however, I have had trouble finding similar information in C#.

Here is what I have mimicked so far:

```
var describeTableResponse = _client.DescribeTable(tableName);
var responseStatusCode = describeTableResponse.HttpStatusCode;

if (responseStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    return true;
}
else if(responseStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
    var error = // get detailed information; looking for ResourceNotFoundException      
}

throw new AmazonDynamoDBException("Error performing the DescribeTable operation");
```

Above, `client` is a correctly configured DB client of type `AmazonDynamoDBClient`.

Any thoughts on how to do the equivalent of:

```
$error_type = $response->body->__type;
$error_code = explode('#', $error_type)[1];
if($error_code == 'ResourceNotFoundException')
{
    echo "Table ".$table_name." exists.";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up going a completely different route due to the specification surrounding the .Net `DescribeTable()` function -- it throws the `ResourceNotFoundException`.

```
try
{
    _client.DescribeTable(tableName);
}
catch (AmazonServiceException amazonServiceException)
{
    if (amazonServiceException.GetType() != typeof(ResourceNotFoundException))
    {
        throw;
    }

    return false;
}

return true;
```